# Use bundle error templates in Symfony 3 app

Tags: symfony, templates, exception, twig, bundle

I have a MyBundle bundle which I use in many Symfony applications.
This bundle provides common things which are shared across these applications, such as Controllers, Entities, templates, etc.

I would like the bundle to provide error templates as well.
I tried to put the templates in MyBundle/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception folder but the application does not use them.

When I copy TwigBundle folder from MyBundle/Resources into app/Resources then the templates are used as expected. However I do not want to copy the templates into every application's app/Resources folder.

Is it possible to override error templates using MyBundle/Resources instead of app/Resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TwigBundle always by default checks directory `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/` for templates.

If you want to use custom directory you have to override `ExceptionController`.
You can do this in config

```
// app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller: MyBundle:Exception:showException
```

Default Twig ExceptionController can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/master/Controller/ExceptionController.php).

[Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: I like your solution. Thanks!